# Measurement and probability in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

I am not sure if I am understanding this right, but I was wondering what is actually what happen when you measure in quantum mechanics. When you have a system, you can describe it has a wave function in position space $ \psi(x) $ and it could be a superposition of different states of the system, with some probabilities. Also this function should follow the continuity equation if the total probability is conserved, $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} |\psi|^2 +\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{J}=0$

Looking at this equation my question is, can I think about 'measure' like a quench from my state $\psi(x)$ to the measure state $\psi_m$ where probability is conserved? I mean, you have a state
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{i} \psi_i $$
you measure and find $\psi_m$, Can I understand this like the probability for $\psi_m$ has evolved following the continuity equation from my initial state $\psi(x)$ to the measure state $\psi_m(x)$? So the probability evolve from the initial one for $\psi_m$ to 1, isn't it? I cannot see reasons to find if I am wrong or right